# Comparator won't work with Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

So I'm working on a comparator problem and I can't figure out why the `Array.sort` in this first class is giving me the error of:

> The method sort(T[], Comparator) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList,  CalorieComparator)

Restaurant Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Restaurant {
    private ArrayList<Edible> elist;

    public Restaurant() {
    }

    public void addEdibleItem(Edible item){
        elist.add(item);
    }

    public List<Edible> orderByCalories(){
        Arrays.sort(elist, new CalorieComparator());
    }
```

CalorieComparator class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class CalorieComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
        Edible thisfood = (Edible)o1;
        Edible otherfood = (Edible)o2;
        if(thisfood.getCalories() > otherfood.getCalories())
            return 1;
        else if (thisfood.getCalories() < otherfood.getCalories())
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to think about implementing a Comparator<Edible> instead of casting your objects in the compare method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is different from a Java array; since you're using a List, `Arrays.sort` won't help you here.

Consider [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring your actual problem with Arrays.sort vs. Collections.sort (that has been beautifully answered), it might be a good idea to implement a `Comparator<Edible>` instead of casting your Objects in the compare method:

```
public class CalorieComparator implements Comparator<Edible> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Edible o1, Edible o2) {        
    if (o1.getCalories() > o2.getCalories()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (o1.getCalories() < o2.getCalories()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.sort` takes an array as its first argument.  To sort a collection such as a list, use `Collections.sort`.

```
Collection.sort(elist, new CalorieComparator());
```

Also, note that your method won't compile because you aren't returning a `List<Edible>`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggest the problem is actually caused by the list being passed instead where an array is expected, nothing to do with the comparator.

Try the following instead

```
Arrays.sort(elist.toArray(), new CalorieComparator());
```

But with that you will not get the desired result ultimately, because it will sort the brand new array just created instead of the list itself. But that you should get the idea of what the error message was trying to say. Just make sure not to pass a list there, it's meant to sort an array and not a list.

As others have suggested please use the `Collections.sort` method instead to get the desired result.

Also, just a side note, you should extend the generic version `Comparator<T>` instead of the non-generic one.

Comment: While that will compile, it will sort an array that cannot again be accessed past that line.

Comment: @Vulcan: I was updating my answer. That's a good point though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(elist, new CalorieComparator());
```

You are calling a `sort()` of `Arrays` class with `ArrayList`,  `ArrayList` belongs to `Collection` family not an `Array`.

your error will resolved
if you use [Collectinss.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)