# ArrayList<File> sorting by file.length()

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort an `ArrayList` by the size of the `File`s contained in it.

```
public class ArraySorting implements Comparator<File> {

    public ArraySorting() { }

    public ArrayList<File> sort(ArrayList<File> arrayOfFiles) {
        Arrays.sort(arrayOfFiles, new ArraySorting());
        return arrayOfFiles;
    }

    public int compare( File a, File b ) {
        long aSize = a.length();
        long bSize = b.length();
        if ( aSize < bSize ) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (aSize > bSize) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error:

> The method sort(T[], Comparator) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, ArraySorting).

Comment: are you using Collections.sort(...)?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a list, not an array! Use `Collections.sort(arrayOfFiles, new ArraySorting())`.

Comment: Did you try googling your error at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889314/comparator-wont-work-with-arrays-sort

Comment: FYI you can just `return a.length() - b.length();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` expects an array. Use `Collections.sort` in order to sort a `List`.

```
public ArrayList<File> sort(ArrayList<File> arrayOfFiles) 
{
    Collections.sort(arrayOfFiles, new ArraySorting());
    return arrayOfFiles;
}
```